# Python code keeps choosing the same random character

Tags: python

So basically like the title say. I made a reddit bot and made it choose a random character everytime someone post a specific phrase, but it keeps choosing the same character for everyone who types the phrase

this is my code

```
phrase = '!randomcharacter'


import random
char = ["character 1", "character 2", "character 3", 
"character 4", "character 5"] 

rand_item = random.choice(char)


for comment in subreddit.stream.comments():
    if  phrase in comment.body :
         reply = 'your character is' + str(rand_item)
         comment.reply(reply)
```

For example it'll choose character 3 randomly but answer it to every one

Comment: `rand_item = random.choice(char)` must be called _several_ times...: https://xkcd.com/221/

Answer (score 1):

That's because you defined the returned value of the function. The variable has one value that always stays the same (unless you change it). What you need to change is this:

```
reply = 'your character is' + str(rand_item)
```

to this:

```
reply = 'your character is' + str(random.choice(char))
```

or you could change the variable each time.